# How do I setup an async method which only returns a Task in strict mode in Moq 4.13.1?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, moq

I have an async method returning a `Task`:

```
public virtual async Task IReturnATask(Guid settingId)
```

When I try to set it up like this in my unit test,

```
_service.Setup(m => m.IReturnATask(guid));
```

Moq complains:

> "Invocation needs to return a value and therefore must have a corresponding setup that provides it."

How should I define the setup of this async method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Task` is still needed to allow the `await` to flow to completion when exercising the test.

So it needs to be setup to return a `Task`.

[`Task.CompletedTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask) can be used for this

```
//...

_service
    .Setup(m => m.IReturnATask(It.Any<Guid>()))
    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

//...
```